# Are there any specific requirements for a Swing component to be run in JavaFX environment?

Tags: java, javafx, gantt-chart

My company have a web application product for distribution planning and scheduling. An important part of it is a gantt chart component where user can fine tune the schedules. Currently the gantt chart component is pure javascript+dhtml.

I am currently looking into the possibility of moving to JavaFX to get richer interactivity and generally nicer UI.
We found this (100%) Swing component called FlexGantt (http://www.dlsc.com/Java_Gantt_Chart_for_Swing.html) and curious to know **whether there are any specific requirements for a Swing component to be run in JavaFX environment** before we actually spend time to learn JavaFX.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to this link there shouldn't be any problems:

http://javafx.com/samples/ExercisingSwing/index.html

--Dirk
www.dlsc.com :-)

Comment: hi dirk.
just curious, how could you found this post? :)